# Relationship between $\vec x \cdot\vec y$ and $\|\vec y\|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a subspace $\mathsf V$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and a vector $\vec x$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\vec y = \operatorname{proj}_{\mathsf V}\vec x$. What is the relationship between the following quantities?

Relationship between $\vec x \cdot\vec y$ and $\|\vec y\|^2$

Not sure where to go with this

Comment: Do you have any formulas involving the projection of $x$ on $V$?

Answer (score 2):

Since we can write $\vec x=\vec x_1+\vec x_2$ for some $\vec x_1\in{\sf V}$
and $\vec x_2\in{\sf V}^\perp$. So by the definition of projection,
$\vec y=\operatorname{proj}_{\mathsf V}\vec x=\vec x_1$ and hence
$$\vec x\cdot \vec y=(\vec x_1+\vec x_2)\cdot\vec x_1
=\Vert \vec x_1\Vert^2+\vec x_2\cdot\vec x_1
=\Vert \vec x_1\Vert^2=\Vert \vec y\Vert^2.$$

Comment: How do you get from $= ||\vec x_1||^2 + \vec x_2 \cdot \vec x_1 =$  $||\vec x_1||^2$ ?

Comment: @LaneFord Because of the assumption that $\vec x_1\in{\sf V}$ and $\vec x_2\in{\sf V}^\perp$, their dot product must be vanished.

Comment: I just was able to see that. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

By $y = \text{proj}_v  x$ we have that 
$$y = \frac{v^T x}{v^Tv}v.$$

Thus, $$\langle x,y\rangle=x^T\cdot \dfrac{v^Tx }{\|v\|_2^2}\cdot v= \dfrac{v^Tx}{\|v\|_2^2}\cdot v^Tx= \dfrac{\langle v,x \rangle^2}{\|v\|_2^2},$$
whereas:

$$\|y\|_2^2= \left|\frac{v^Tx}{v^Tv} \right|^2\cdot \|v\|_2^2=
 \dfrac{\langle v,x \rangle^2}{\|v\|_2^4}\cdot \|v\|^2_2 =\langle x, y\rangle.$$